# Older sister's get to celebrate their birthday first right?

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man taking his daughter to her new friends birthday party one Saturday in *spring* when he happened to overhear his daughter's friend explaining her party to his daughter. saying:

```
"I'm the oldest so we usually celebrate on my birthday, but Mom says they don't take 
 reservations here on Friday so we're having the party on Brittney birthday instead"
```

The man didn't think much of the conversation until it was time to open gifts and he saw two identical girls at the center table start opening gifts together.  He hadn't realized his daughter's new friend had a twin.  But wait, if they were twins how could one be an older sibling with a birthday on Friday and the other have a birthday on Saturday?

Some clarifying details:

Tiny Hint 1:

> The birthday girl is indeed an identical twin and was referring to the Brittney she was referring to was her twin sister

Hint 2:

> The girls were born hours apart

Hint 3:

> Their parents were on a vacation when the kids were born

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8813/older-twins-birthday-is-one-day-after-youngers?rq=1

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu I think that's a more complicated question than this one. Hint 3 seems redundant. As is the fact their birthday is in spring.

Comment: @dsollen Is the question really worded the way you want it to be? It seems very reasonable to have an older twin born on a Friday and the younger twin born several hours later (per Hint 2) on a Saturday.

Comment: If not, then it is a duplicate

Comment: I read the title "older ... first right?" to mean: it is strange that the younger sister has the birthday first, ie. OP did not mean it to be worded the way it is.

Comment: This is either a mistakenly worded duplicate, or a non-puzzle. Either way, I'll have to VTC.

Answer (score 4):

> The older twin was born on Friday shortly before midnight and the younger was born on Saturday.

Because

> The parents being on vacation and the birthday being in spring are red herrings.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the

> parents being on an airplane, crossing the dateline. One daughter born before the dateline, the other after.

And

> Maybe on the day in spring where daylight saving becomes active, adding an extra spice to the question