# Murder in a bar

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, mystery

Two men enter a bar. They are served identical drinks with poison. One lives; the other dies. How is that possible?

> HINT: I have not specified what _____ the poison is in

Comment: Ouch. It was an iron bar.

Comment: I'm not seeing any reason for close votes on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Poisoned Iced Tea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/poisoned-iced-tea)

Comment: If your puzzles are coming from another source, be sure to cite from where they came.

Comment: @GOTO0 sorry I didn't see that puzzle. It was asked way before I became a part of this community so I didn't know it was there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because

> They had ice in their drinks and the one who drank their's faster lived, because the ice did not mix with the water.

Also for the hint

> The blank refers to the word 'state' as in state of matter

Comment: I think this should be the answer, although the problem seems to lack definition. +1 from me!

Comment: Correct! I will select this once six minutes have passed

Comment: Honestly, if the poison was concentrated, even a small trickle could have killed him

Answer (score 13):

If you want lateral thinking, it could also be because

> They were *served* drinks with poison in them. It's quite possible that only one *drank* their drink and so he died but the other one lived.

Comment: Had the same thought six seconds later.

Comment: close, but quite off the mark

Comment: @hexomino great minds think alike..... ;) oh well, back to the drawing board

Comment: I could have selected this one, i liked the thinking but when they are served, they obviously have to drink it

Answer (score 5):

A possible reason is because:

> One of the men accidentally dropped his glass on the ground, then went to clean it up, slipped, and landed in the broken glass.

Comment: Hey! Well tried but it is not the answer, Nevertheless, a good try.+1 from me

Answer (score 5):

Taking a page out of Princess Bride:

> One had built up an immunity to the poison and assassinated the other man.

Comment: Well, this seems like a change in the story but nevermind, a good try +1

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that

> The phrase is meant to be interpreted as "They are served identical drinks, with poison", meaning they were served 2 drinks, and also poison, which only one of them drank?

Comment: That thought could have been right but the poison was mixed with the drinks in some form right, Still, a good try

Answer (score 4):

> The drinks contain poisoned ice cubes; one man drinks slowly, giving them time to melt, while the other drinks quickly and thus doesn't get much of the poison.

Comment: Sorry! this although is correct, another user has answered before you, nevertheless i will mark it as +1 so that you will gain some reputation for your answer

Answer (score 2):

I think that

> One of them drank immediately, so he got poisoned, while the other waited for a long time such that the poison falls to the bottom, then had his drink!

Answer (score 1):

> It was not the liquid in the drink that was poisoned, but the garnish - e.g. the orange slice on the side of an old fashioned glass, or an olive in a martini. One of the men ate or squeezed their garnish into the drink, the other did not.