# My friend got poisoned but I didn't

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Last night I went to a bar with my roommate. We ordered the same drink (Campari spritz of course) and I quickly begin to drink mine.
My friend is much slower than me: when I finished my drink they had barely drink a quarter of their so I order another drink (another Campari spritz of course).

When I finished the second one they were still drinking their first, so I ordered another one and then another again.

After my fourth drink, they finally finished their drink so we paid, we exited and we got back home.

Today I found them dead in their bed, the doctor said they were poisoned.

The poison was in the drinks and all the drinks were poured by the same bottle. Why did my roommate die but I did not?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/poisoned-iced-tea Duplicate?

Comment: The question does say "The poison was in the Spritz"; arguably that rules out the solution in that earlier puzzle. (On the other hand, without that statement I would think the other puzzle's solution extremely likely to be the solution to this one.) @melfnt, would you like to let us know whether the intended solution to this puzzle is the same as that?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. I searched for the answer on PSE but I couldn't find it so I thought it was never posted here

Comment: Why doesn't this link work: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=Ice+is%3Aanswer

Comment: If I knew that a similar puzzle had been already posted I wouldn't have posted this

Comment: No worries, it's still a good puzzle. That search doesn't work probably because the keyword is spoilertagged in the answer to the older puzzle.